# "Does it mean that she won?" or "it means that she won?"

Tags: relative-pronouns, interrogatives

Scenario:

> My sister arrives in my house crying, after a competition. 
>   So, we can't know if she won or lost yet.

So, someone ask:

"Does it mean that she won?"

or

"It means that she won?"

What sentence should I use and why?

Comment: You could use either, colloquially; intonation would give the meaning, rather than the actual sentence construction. Grammatically, & for written English, the first would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that she won?
> It means that she won?

The difference between these two sentences is that the first one sounds like a question and the second one sounds like a guess or an uncertain statement. If you say:

> Does it mean that she won?

you're saying that you don't know whether she won. If you say:

> It means that she won?

You're saying that you think she won, but you're not sure. You could also say this after someone else said she won, and you're confused or skeptical. For instance:

> Person 1: Your sister is crying!
>
> Person 2: Don't worry; it means that she won her competition.
>
> Person 1: It means that she *won*?

Here, Person 1 is surprise because he/she doesn't expect someone to cry when something good happens. His question expresses confusion and mild disbelief.

When talking about someone else's actions, "that" is more common than "it". Also, in casual speech, the "that" in "mean that she" may be dropped. So a more natural, casual version of the first sentence is:

> Does that mean she won?